# Error (Subquery returns more than 1 row) al ejecutar un DELETE en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un error a la hora de ejecutar una sentencia de mysql, es un simple DELETE, lo raro es que he usado mil veces esta opcion en mi sistema web, pero hasta ahora me da este error, el query es simple:

```
DELETE FROM detalleAgenda WHERE codResumen=881
```

Pero ahora que quiero eliminarlo me tira este error siempre:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

No le encuentro logica al error debido a que no tengo ninguna subquery en este metodo, es un simple delete, la tabla tiene una llave primaria, y 3 foraneas, el delete se ejecuta con un WHERE hacia una de las llaves foraneas, la conexion de esa tabla a la otra es de 1:1, es decir que el resumen solo puede estar en un detalle. Por lo que no deberia dar ese error, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Si ejecuto esa query directamente desde phpmyadmin, sigue mostrando ese mismo error

Comment: ¿No será que tienes algún `TRIGGER` programado con respecto a esa tabla? Cuando se intenta el `DELETE` el `TRIGGER` se dispara, produciendo el error que nos muestras en la pregunta.

Comment: Para ver los `TRIGGER` ligados a tu tabla puedes ejecutar esta consulta: **`SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'detalleAgenda';`** en los resultados debes revisar los `TRIGGER` que sean del tipo `AFTER DELETE` o `BEFORE DELETE`

Comment: El error era debido a un trigger que tenia una subconsulta que ya no funcionaba como debia a cambios de logistica de la propia base de datos, por sus comentarios la pregunta ya esta resuelta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es evidente que el error no puede venir de esta consulta, porque como dices no hay ninguna subconsulta en ella:

```
DELETE FROM detalleAgenda WHERE codResumen=881
```

Cuando esto ocurra, debes pensar en los `TRIGGER` que dispara tu tabla `detalleAgenda`, en alguno de ellos debe estar ocurriendo el error.

Para encontrar los `TRIGGERS` específicos puedes ejecutar la consulta siguiente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS 
WHERE 
    EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='detalleAgenda' 
    AND EVENT_MANIPULATION='DELETE';
```

Puedes aplicar más filtros, [usando las columnas de la tabla `TRIGGERS` de `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-triggers-table.html).

Esa consulta te arrojará la definición de los `TRIGGERS` que dispara `detalleAgenda` cuando algún evento del tipo `DELETE` ocurre, en alguno de ellos debe estar el error descrito en el mensaje.